# iOS - Faster Way To Load UIImages From URL's

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimage

I have an app that when you first open it, the main view gets all your friends and their profile pictures and loads a `UITableView` with your friends' names, usernames, and profile pictures in each cell. The problem is that the `UITableView` takes longer to load all the friends if you have a lot of them, about 30 for example (takes about 5-8 seconds). I store all these images in a dictionary associated with the friend's username so I can reuse them for later, but the main problem is how long it takes for all the images to load when the app first starts up. This is the code I have for now that does it while iterating over each friend:

```
[auth.loggedInUser getFriendsSuccessCallback:^(NSArray* friends){
    for (User* friend in friends) {
        if (![weakSelf.friendImageDictionary.allKeys containsObject:friend.userName])
        {
            UIImage *profilePicture;
            if (!friend.profilePicture) {
                profilePicture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ProfilePic"];
            }
            else
            {
                NSURL *profilePictureURL = [NSURL URLWithString:friend.profilePicture];
                NSData * profilePictureData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:profilePictureURL];
                profilePicture = [UIImage imageWithData:profilePictureData];
            }
            if (profilePicture == nil)
            {
                profilePicture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ProfilePic"];
            }
            [weakSelf.friendImageDictionary setObject:profilePicture forKey:friend.userName];
        }
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [weakSelf.tableView reloadData];
    });
}
```

Any advice on how to significantly reduce the amount of time it takes to load all these images?

PROGRESS:

Okay so I'm using `AFNetworking` with the following code:

```
[auth.loggedInUser getFriendsSuccessCallback:^(NSArray* friends){
    NSMutableArray *profilePictureRequests = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (User* friend in friends) {
        if (![weakSelf.friendImageDictionary.allKeys containsObject:friend.userName])
        {
            if (!friend.profilePicture) {
                UIImage *profilePicture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ProfilePic"];
                [weakSelf.friendImageDictionary setObject:profilePicture forKey:friend.userName];
            }
            else
            {
                NSURL *profilePictureURL = [NSURL URLWithString:friend.profilePicture];
                NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:profilePictureURL];
                AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest];
                requestOperation.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];
                [requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, UIImage* profilePicture) {
                    NSLog(@"Response: %@", profilePicture);
                    if (profilePicture == nil)
                    {
                        profilePicture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ProfilePic"];
                    }
                    [weakSelf.friendImageDictionary setObject:profilePicture forKey:friend.userName]; 
                } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                    NSLog(@"Image error: %@", error);
                }];
                [profilePictureRequests addObject:requestOperation];
            }
        }
    }
    for (AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation in profilePictureRequests)
    {
        [requestOperation start];
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [weakSelf.tableView reloadData];
        weakSelf.dashboardViewController.loadingCoverView.hidden = YES;
        [weakSelf.dashboardViewController.tableActivityIndicator stopAnimating];
        NSLog(@"FINISHED LOADING ALL PROFILE PICTURES");
    });
}
```

Basically what I did was store an `AFHTTPRequestOperation` in an `NSMutableArray` for each image that needed to be loaded. After that, I iterated over the `NSMutableArray` and started each `AFHTTPRequestOperation`.

ISSUES:

This just made loading all the images EXTREMELY fast, but I think I'm doing it incorrectly. My loading view with my activity indicator finishes and disappears BEFORE all the images are finished downloading and being added to my `NSMutableDictionary` when it should be happening AFTER all of them are downloaded and added. Is there a way for me to make my loading view and activity indicator disappear AFTER all the `UIImage` download background threads have finished?

ADDITIONAL QUESTION ABOUT `AFNetworking`:

Is the way I'm doing it (making about 30 image downloading background threads happen at the same time in this case) not good practice with `AFNetworking`? Will it lead to future problems if, let's say, a user has over 100 friends and there are over 100 image downloading background threads happening at the same time?

Comment: sounds like you should reduce the size of the images server side.

Comment: This has been done, and loading time for a bulk of images is still a problem, especially when users will have more friends. I'm think in the range of setting a new background thread for each image that has to be loaded from the url. Is this possible?

Comment: Use AFNetworking and async downloads quite easy

Comment: @james--->I started using AFNetworking which helped, but I'm still experiencing issues which I included as I updated my question with my progress. Can you please check it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably won't reduce the download time, but you can make it seem faster.

You are using synchronous downloads on the main thread, a very bad idea.

There are libraries like AFNetworking that make setting up async downloads quite easy. Or if you want to do it yourself you can use `NSURLSession`, or NSURLSession (which was deprecated in iOS 9.)

Comment: My code snippet is within an API call block to my server, so I'm technically loading the images from a background thread. I'll update my code really quick.

Comment: Are you **certain** that the success callback takes place on the main thread? You can use NSThread isMainThread to tell. Add a debug statement like this inside the success callback: `NSLog("isMainThread = %d", [NSThread isMainThread]);`

Comment: You should probably refactor your code to load one image at a time and update the UI as each image downloads. A framework like AFNetworking makes this much easier.

Comment: @DuncanC---> Yes, I ran that snippet and my code is running on a background thread except when I make UI changes like reloading the table view. I started using `AFNetworking` which helped, but I'm still experiencing issues which I included as I updated my question with my progress. Can you please check it out?

Answer (score 0):

When working with UIImages, I often use SDWebImage: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

You can check out it's README.md for more specific details, but it adds support for remote images coming from the web asynchronously with caching.

An example of its use:

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>

[self.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]
```

Comment: So if I get use this library and include this statement in a for loop, for example, will the images be downloading all at the same time on different threads or will the for loop wait for the image to download until going to the next iteration?

Comment: Main use of SDwebImage is it saves images in cache so that from second they will load from cache and we clear cache when you memory warning.